# ADF Skinning - change image of selected checkbox

Tags: css

```
.checkbox  input[type="checkbox"]{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 23px;
        height: 21px;
        margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_391ce065f36b1460c4845fa9b5173fba.png) top no-repeat  ;
        cursor: pointer;
        appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;



}
.checkbox  input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
      background: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_391ce065f36b1460c4845fa9b5173fba.png)0px bottom !important;
}
```

I created a checkbox and changed it's style when I checked it image not changed.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks ,
I resolved it by this solution

```
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: -1px 5px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
   background: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_a967b1e8ddfb00be4a2edf9abd4371c3.png)0px top no-repeat  ;
    cursor: pointer;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;


}
 .checkbox af|selectBooleanCheckbox::content  input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
      background:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_a967b1e8ddfb00be4a2edf9abd4371c3.png) 0px bottom !important   ;
}
```